# How to create a formula that takes specific words from one column and autofills text into another column

Tags: excel, formula, autofill

I know a bit about excel but I hoping for some help. I am creating a simple document. I would like to create a formula that takes text from one column, and automatically states "Yes" if applicable in another column.

For instance, in Row B there are multiple choices. When "Taco"is typed into Row B, I want auto fill "Yes" into Row C.

I have tried multiple formulas such as

```
=if(C3:C100, "Taco", D3:D100, "Yes")
=if($C "Taco", $D "Yes")
```

and a bunch of other ones i found on google.

Any help would be appreciated. I realize it isn't the most time consuming to just add yes to a column, but I would like to learn how to effectively create new formulas besides very simple ones.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `=if(C3:C100, "Taco", D3:D100, "Yes")`??? if you want to set `D3:D100` to be "Yes," you had to put on `D3:D100` with `=if(EXACT(C3:C100, "Taco"), "Yes", "" )`. and sorry for the flag. this is not programming, but how to use **excel formula** in general..

Comment: To how I understand your question: if C1 is checking B1 for "Taco" then in C1 use =if(B1="Taco","Yes","") and drag it across row C. If there are multiple choices then you can use =if(or(B1="Taco",B1="Fruit"),"Yes","") and drag across

Comment: @PapaKojo I think you have answered the question. Why not post it as a proper answer? For the OP, you may want to read this [article](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-if-function) and do more research online before asking future questions as there are ample examples online of how to use the **IF** function that you are struggling with :) Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way.

Comment: Thank you all, I had researched online for the last few days but I could not figure out why when I typed the formulas the way they were on articles I kept receiving errors. I was finally able to figure it out. I really appreciate all the help. And sorry that I put this in the wrong category. I am really not that knowledgeable about IT In general.